# The HttpClient factory already has a registered client with the type c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, httpclient, .net-6.0

I need to inject HttpClient into multiple classes with the same interface

```
 service.AddTransient<IFooService, AFooService>();
            service.AddHttpClient<IFooService, AFooService>((serviceProvider, httpClient) => 
            {
            }).AddHttpMessageHandler<AzureDefaultCredentialsAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

however when I try and add more  eg

```
 service.AddTransient<IFooService, BFooService>();
            service.AddHttpClient<IFooService, BFooService>((serviceProvider, httpClient) => 
            {
            }).AddHttpMessageHandler<AzureDefaultCredentialsAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

I get the error

`The HttpClient factory already has a registered client with the type 'Project.IFooService'. Client types must be unique. Consider using inheritance to create multiple unique types with the same API surface.`

I know the error is becuase I already have IFooService registered to inject a HttpClient, but I have no idea how to fix it.

any suggestions would be appriciated.

Comment: I think you can just pass the implementation(s) to avoid this error: `service.AddHttpClient<AFooService>()` & `service.AddHttpClient<BFooService>()`

Answer (score 0):

You can register typed `HttpClient` via instance:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<AFooService>(// ... your setup);
```

And then if you need to "reabstract" those to interface (assuming you need them as a collection):

```cs
services.AddTransient<IFooService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AFooService>());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//BEFORE      


 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration 
  configuration)
    {
        //client to request Worldline services         
       services.AddHttpClient<WorldlineStandardHttpClient>().WithProxy();



    }
```

//AFTER

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration 
      configuration)
        {
            //client to request Worldline services
                  
        services.AddHttpClient<WorldlineStandardHttpClient>("AnyUnique Name").WithProxy();


        }
```

CHANGE: i used another overloaded method of AddHttpClient and added a name to it. and it worked